# Converting A Riemann Sum into an Integral

Tags: calculus

The expression given is:

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{2M}{3N}*(\frac{2}{3} - (\frac{2}{3N})^k)$$

I was able to compute the limit and arrive at:

$$\frac{4M}{9}$$

Does this amount to integrating the function from 1 to infinity? If so how do I not integrate but extract the function? How do I know the function from this Riemann Sum?

Comment: It is difficult to read.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I mathjax-ified it. Could you peer review the formatting?

Comment: No, it does not "amount to" integrating.    In fact, the limit as $N \to \infty$ should not involve $N$ after you evaluate it.

Comment: @GEdgar fixed it thanks. So You're saying 4M/9 is NOT the integral of the function from 1 to infinity?